# 403 Forbidden on CORS request from local

Tags: apache, cors, gluu

I am working with [Gluu Server](https://www.gluu.org/) and trying to get the OpenID Connect configuration from the `/.well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint through a CORS/AJAX request (for use with an Angular app). However, when I try to request the endpoint from a locally hosted app/HTML file with XHR requesting the endpoint, I receive a `403 Forbidden` error.

This only seems to happen when the request stems from a local context, i.e. Angular's development server or a local HTML file requesting the endpoint. If I open the same HTML file that performs the AJAX request, hosted on a server, it works.

The testing HTML file looks like the following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = 'https://example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration';

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        req.open('GET', url, true);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        req.onload = () => {
            if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
                console.log('[XHR SUCCESS]');
                var el = document.getElementById('content');
                el.innerHTML = req.responseText;
            } else {
                console.log('[XHR ERROR]', req);
            }
        }

        req.onerror = () => {
            console.log('[XHR CONNECTION ERROR]');
        }
        req.send();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Requesting from local file

As mentioned above, when requesting from a local HTML file, I receive the `403 Forbidden` error.

In the browser console (Chrome), two errors are output:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

The only output on the server, that I have found, relating to this, is in the file `/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log`:

```
example.com:443 <IP> - - [11/Mar/2019:10:45:20 +0000] "OPTIONS /.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" 403 3763 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
```

The server receives the following (from the `log_forensic` module for Apache) when requested from local:

```
OPTIONS /.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1|Host:example.com|Connection:keep-alive|Pragma:no-cache|Cache-Control:no-cache|Access-Control-Request-Method:GET|Origin:null|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36|Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type|Accept:*/*|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
```

### Requesting from server-hosted file

When doing the exact same thing as above, but with the HTML file hosted on a server, the request completes successfully.

Output in the access log:

```
example.com:443 <IP> - - [11/Mar/2019:11:06:46 +0000] "OPTIONS /.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" 200 779 "http://example.org/xhr-cors.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
example.com:443 <IP> - - [11/Mar/2019:11:06:46 +0000] "GET /.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1" 200 6629 "http://example.org/xhr-cors.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
```

From `log_forensic`:

```
OPTIONS /.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1|Host:example.com|Connection:keep-alive|Access-Control-Request-Method:GET|Origin:http%3a//example.org|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36|Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type|Accept:*/*|Referer:http%3a//example.org/xhr-cors.html|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9

GET /.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1|Host:example.com|Connection:keep-alive|Origin:http%3a//example.org|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36|Content-Type:application/json|Accept:*/*|Referer:http%3a//example.org/xhr-cors.html|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
```

### Apache configuration

The configuration for Apache on the server is

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        Redirect  / https://example.com/
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
        ServerName example.com:443

        LogLevel warn
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK

#               SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
        SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1
        Timeout 60
                ProxyTimeout 60

        # Security headers
#        Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
                Header always set X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"
                Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
#        Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://example.com"
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"

        Header edit Set-Cookie ^((?!session_state).*)$ $1;HttpOnly
        SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

                # Unset X-ClientCert to make sure that we not get certificate in request
        RequestHeader unset X-ClientCert

                # Turn off support for true Proxy behaviour as we are acting as a transparent proxy
        ProxyRequests Off

                # Turn off VIA header as we know where the requests are proxied
        ProxyVia Off

                # Turn on Host header preservation so that the servlet container
                # can write links with the correct host and rewriting can be avoided.
        ProxyPreserveHost On

                # Preserve the scheme when proxying the request to Jetty
                RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" env=HTTPS

                Header unset ETag
        FileETag None

        RedirectMatch ^(/)$ /identity/

                # Set the permissions for the proxy
                <Proxy *>
                  AddDefaultCharset off
                  Order deny,allow
                  Allow from all
                </Proxy>

        <Location /oxauth>
                ProxyPass http://localhost:8081/oxauth retry=5 connectiontimeout=60 timeout=60
#                Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        <LocationMatch /oxauth/auth/cert/cert-login>
            SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
            SSLVerifyDepth 10
            SSLOptions -StdEnvVars +ExportCertData

                        # Forward certificate to destination server
            RequestHeader set X-ClientCert %{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s
        </LocationMatch>

        <Location /idp>
                ProxyPass http://localhost:8086/idp retry=5 connectiontimeout=60 timeout=60
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        <Location /identity>
                ProxyPass http://localhost:8082/identity retry=5 connectiontimeout=60 timeout=60
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        <Location /cas>
                ProxyPass http://localhost:8083/cas retry=5 connectiontimeout=60 timeout=60
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        <Location /oxauth-rp>
                ProxyPass http://localhost:8085/oxauth-rp retry=5 connectiontimeout=60 timeout=60
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        <Location /asimba>
                ProxyPass http://localhost:8084/asimba retry=5 connectiontimeout=60 timeout=60
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        <Location /passport>
                ProxyPass http://localhost:8090/passport retry=5 connectiontimeout=60 timeout=60
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        <Location /casa>
                ProxyPass http://localhost:8091/casa retry=5 connectiontimeout=60 timeout=60
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

       <LocationMatch "/.well-known/openid-configuration">
               ProxyPass http://localhost:8081/oxauth/.well-known/openid-configuration
               Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
       </LocationMatch>

#                        ProxyPass /.well-known/openid-configuration http://localhost:8081/oxauth/.well-known/openid-configuration
ProxyPass /.well-known/simple-web-discovery http://localhost:8081/oxauth/.well-known/simple-web-discovery
ProxyPass        /.well-known/webfinger http://localhost:8081/oxauth/.well-known/webfinger
        ProxyPass        /.well-known/uma2-configuration http://localhost:8081/oxauth/restv1/uma2-configuration
        ProxyPass        /.well-known/fido-configuration http://localhost:8081/oxauth/restv1/fido-configuration
        ProxyPass        /.well-known/fido-u2f-configuration http://localhost:8081/oxauth/restv1/fido-configuration
        ProxyPass        /.well-known/scim-configuration http://localhost:8082/identity/restv1/scim-configuration
        ServerAlias        example.com
        SSLCertificateFile        /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I have commented out the

```
ProxyPass /.well-known/openid-configuration http://localhost:8081/oxauth/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

directive and introduced the

```
<LocationMatch "/.well-known/openid-configuration">
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8081/oxauth/.well-known/openid-configuration
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</LocationMatch>
```

directive to add CORS header(s).

### Other

Other things I've tried to figure out what the issue is:

- Performed a `GET` request to the endpoint through Postman, which completed successfully.
- Performed an `OPTIONS` request to the endpoint through Postman, which completed successfully.

I'd very much appreciate some input on this as it has me pretty stumped and being unable to work from local when developing is cumbersome. If any clarification is needed, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure on gluu side but you can try chrome cors plugin to enable it:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: @Jingwei This wasn't exactly the answer, but your suggestion did put me on the right track by making me examine the request and response headers for the fifth (or something) time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this problem was an amalgamation of two unrelated things.

First, and this is mostly conjecture, it *seems* that Chrome blocks requests from a local file (the HTML file) and simply provides output that is, to me, very confusing. I.e. the `403` error *might* be because Chrome blocks the CORS request somehow. I tried running Chrome with various flags, e.g. `--disable-web-security` and `--allow-file-access-from-files`, but this did not change the output from the local HTML file. So, the local file request still fails and I don't really know the exact reason. But, since this was just for testing it is not that relevant, for me, currently.

Secondly, an erroneous implementation in an interceptor in the Angular project overwrote all headers for requests. After fixing this, the local server was able to request the endpoint.

It just so happened that the output from the two different issues looked pretty much identical which threw me off.